# Scala profiler?

Tags: scala, profiler

I started to program in Scala recently. I'm looking for a free Scala profiler. Reading from the language's official site led me to [YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com/), but the program was not a free one.

Googling "scala profiler" didnt give me any relevant result.

So how do I profile my program written in Scala? I prefer a graphical plugin for Netbeans or Eclipse. But if there is no such thing, then a console one will be fine.

Thanks :)

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.lightbend.com/blog/2018-04-09-profiling-JVM-applications/index.html where they talk about how to use this profiler: https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Given that Scala runs on the Java Virtual Machine (`JVM`), you can use the `JVM` tools `JConsole` and `VisualVM` to profile the application. Alternatively *any* Java profiler should work (e.g. YourKit, as you've already mentioned)

[**`VisualVM`**](https://visualvm.java.net/gettingstarted.html) has been bundled with the JDK since `1.6.0_10` and it is based on the NetBeans profiler. You can capture memory usage, code performance hotspots etc:

```
C:> %JAVA_HOME%\bin\jvisualvm
```

Comment: Thank you. I downloaded JVisualVM then followed the guide here https://visualvm.dev.java.net/gettingstarted.html, and it works.

Comment: One more problem: The program only displayed where is the hotspot. How do I make it display in the "hierarchical" mode? i.e. which function calls which. Can JVisualVM do that?

Thanks :)

Comment: @Phuc: yes, you need to take a snapshot for this functionality. The button is above the list of hotspots.

Answer (score 9):

I have tried with jvisualvm (both inside and outside netbeans) but I cannot see any scala method call in the profiling reports (only the underlying java libraries method calls). To me it looks like a bug but I might have missed snomething obvious. Anyway here is a issue report I wrote on netbeans.org with the details:[171388](http://www.netbeans.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=171388)

If anybody here has successfully used JVisualVM to CPU-profile Scala code please let me know.

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  I don't see any Scala methods.

Comment: I've got same problem, but it can be easily solved by clicking "Settings" checkbox on Profiler page and configuring target and ignored classes properly. In my case a java.* ignore rule blocked profileing of underlying Scala code