# Scala Profiler?

Tags: scala, jvm, profiling

There's a question from ~2 years back about a profiler for Scala, but after trying to use Java's VisualVM myself for a while, I find its compatibility with the Scala v2.9.0 bytecode lacking (particularly, the CPU profiling functionality).  There's a huge flurry of error messages having to do with anonymous classes, so instead of trying to fight it I was wondering if there were any other profilers ready for Scala 2.9?

Comment: Actually I'm using VisualVM for profiling Scala code and it works out very well. Buth with the instrumenting and the sampling CPU profiler. What exactly are your problems?

Comment: Intesting. I've never been able to get instrumenting CPU profiler to work with VisualVM. OS X 10.6, Java 1.6.0_24. It's been a real frustration.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scala profiler?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340082/scala-profiler)

Comment: @KiptonBarros VisualVM works like a charm here (OS X 10.8, Java 1.6.0_ …, but I think also with 10.6 — it works for me since ever).

Answer (score 5):

*There's a huge flurry of error messages having to do with anonymous classes, so instead of trying to fight it*

AFAIK, Scala uses exceptions for flow control: see [this](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/profiling-a-Scala-program-tp3003067p3003702.html). Moreover, in that theme `Yourkit` recommended for Scala profiling. (Personally, I've used it only with Java code and Yourkit was quite nice).

**UPDATE**

Now there is also [HeapAudit](http://engineering.foursquare.com/2012/02/02/heapaudit-jvm-memory-profiler-for-the-real-world/) developed with respect to scala.

Comment: Yourkit has worked perfectly for me, and I'm doing large-scale, performance sensitive code in Scala for LinkedIn. Stack traces can get messy because of the name-mangling but it's not hard to figure out what's going on if you know the code well.